# $y^2 + 4Xy + X = 0$ possesses real roots

Tags: probability, quadratics, uniform-distribution

Suppose $X \sim \mathcal{U}(-1, 3)$. What is le probability that the equation $y^2 + 4Xy + X = 0$ possesses real roots?

Suppose $a=1$, $b=4X$ and $c=X$, then $b^2-4ac = (4X)^2 - 4X = 4X(4X-1) > 0$. Hence, $X>0$ or
$4X-1>0$.

We have $P(X>0 \cup X>\frac{1}{4}) = (1-P(X \le 0)) + (1-P(X\le \frac{1}{4})) = 1.4375 > 1$. It is clear this answer is wrong.

In the answer sheet, it says the answer is $P(X \ge \frac{1}{4}) + P(X \le 0) = \frac{15}{16}$.

Where am I wrong

Comment: $X(4X-1) > 0 $ isn't equivalent to $X>0$ or $4X-1 >0$. It is equivalent to both $X,4X-1$ greater than $0$, or both $X,4X-1$ less than $0$, so $\mathbb P( $ equation has real roots $) = \mathbb P( $ either $X>\frac{1}{4}$ or $X<0)$

Comment: Thanks @DominikKutek!  I understand better now. $(X<0 \cap X< \frac{1}{4}) \cup (X>0 \cap X> \frac{1}{4}) = (X<0 \cup X>\frac{1}{4})$

Comment: Yeah, exactly like that !